# expo detach command is not detaching Android code

Tags: react-native, expo

exp detach command is successfully creating the IOS code but is stuck at downloading android code. Has anyone faced this issue?

I read expo docs but no info on this

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: try upgrading exp to the latest globally and exp detach again

Comment: I'm on version 51.4.0 which I believe is the latest. Did you restart anything?

Comment: No, I did not! I'm planning to get rid of expo at this point. Were you able to get this working?

Comment: Yes, look at my answer below. Detaching seems to be a sensitive process so make sure everything is setup correctly. I ended up not using detach, instead I created a new blank project and added my JS code to it

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue which I solved now! In app.json I had specified `"icon": "./assets/pin.png"` but there was no icon there named that. Adding a icon solved my problem.